# Webview not rendering well on tablet

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm using this library: https://github.com/domitry/elegans to draw some graphics in html/js files. I then integrated it to my Android app. It's not working on the emulator (probably because it doesn't have webgl), but it's working on my phone and on my computer browser. I then tried on a tablet and it's not working (the graph keeps redrawing in different angles). It's weird because it's the same UserAgent.

I used : mWebView.getSettings().getUserAgentString() to check that.
I also tried on the Chrome app of the tablet and I have no problem there (webview and chrome both share the same rendering engine).

Any idea what the issue could be?

My javascript code :

```
function start (val){
    var data = {};

//  if (typeof Android !== 'undefined') {
//      var calib =  JSON.parse(Android.getJsonFichierCalib());
//
//      Android.showToast(calib.axeY.toString());
//      var axeX = calib.axeX;
//      var axeY = calib.axeY;
//      var axeZ = calib.valeur_decimale;
//      //var axeZ = new Array(calib.axeZ.length);
//      //for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
//      //  axeZ[i] = [0*i, 1*i, 2*i, 3*i, 4*i, 5*i, 6*i, 7*i, 8*i, 9*i];
//      //}
//  }
//  else{
        var axeX = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
        var axeY = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];
        var axeZ = new Array(10);
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          axeZ[i] = [0*i, 1*i, 2*i, 3*i, 4*i, 5*i, 6*i, 7*i, 8*i, 9*i];
        }
//  }

    console.log(axeX);
    console.log(axeY);  
    for (var i = 0; i < axeZ.length; i++) {
        console.log(axeZ[i]);   
    }

    var BIGIN=axeX[0], END=axeX[axeX.length-1], INTERVAL = 1;
    width = height = (END - BIGIN)/INTERVAL + 1;
    data.x = [], data.y = [], data.z = [];
    for(var i=0;i< height;i++)data.x.push([]);
    for(var j=0;j< height;j++){
        var x = BIGIN + INTERVAL*j;
        for(var i=0;i< width;i++){
            data.x[i][j] = axeX[j];
            //console.log(data.x[i][j]);
        }
    }
    // for (i=0; i < data.x.length; i++) {
    //    for (j = 0; j < data.x[i].length; j++) { console.log(data.x[j][i]); }
    //    }
    for(var i=0;i< width;i++){
        data.y.push([]);
        var y = BIGIN + INTERVAL*i;
        for(var j=0;j< height;j++){
            data.y[i][j] = axeY[i];
            //console.log(data.x[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(var i=0;i< width;i++){
        data.z.push([]);
        for(var j=0;j< height;j++){
            var x=data.x[i][j], y=data.y[i][j];
            data.z[i][j] = axeZ[i][j];
        }
    }
    d3.select('#vis').datum(data).call(Elegans.SurfacePlot);
};      

window.addEventListener("load", start);
```

My WebView settings :

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(webAppInterface, "Android");
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();

webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
Log.i("WebViewActivity", "UA: " + mWebView.getSettings().getUserAgentString());
```

The tablet is a Nvidia Shield Tablet K1 on Android 6.0 and the WebView is up to date.